# why localhost is not loading after building with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a basic app without a database

```
client
 src
  scripts
   app.js
 dockerfile
 package.json

server
 app.js
 dockerfile
 package.json
```

client dockerfile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /client
RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm
COPY package.json .
RUN pnpm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

server dockerfile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm
COPY ./package.json .
RUN pnpm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

root folder docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - logs:/app/logs
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
  client:
    build: ./client
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client/src:/app/src
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  data:
  logs:
```

on the terminal I ran `docker compose build` which was successful
then `docker compose up` which seems to be working
but when I go to localhost:3000 or 8080 nothing is working

any suggestions ?

Comment: try server:80 ?

Comment: Well there isn't anything running on port `8080`. You have something running on port `3000` and something running on port `80`. You should also go into detail about what "nothing is working" means. Do you get an error page? Or a timeout or something?

Comment: @MarkB Unable to connect